# In Javascript, how do you add search querys to get requests?

Tags: javascript, get, fetch

My program uses a charity database API to show the user charities based on their search. Currently I have it set up so that users can search via keyword but I would like to allow users to be able to add parameters to narrow their search like state, city, or rating. The problem I am having though is that if I include the possibility of the parameter, and the user leaves it blank, it wont complete the get request.

```
function fetchData(search, state){


     let params = {
        app_id: app_id,
        app_key: app_key,
        search: search,
        state: state,
    }



    //this program formats the query paramaters
    let searchQuery = formatQueryParams(params)

   
    let searchURL = url + searchQuery;
    

    fetch(searchURL)
    .then(response =>response.json() )
    .then(data => updateDOM(data))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(`${err.message}`)
      })

}
```

In this case, if the user doesn't add a state, the program would create an error.

Answer (score 0):

I typically just add the field if it's passed in so initialize params without it, if it is passed in, then you can add it to the params.

```
function fetchData(search, state){


 let params = {
    app_id: app_id,
    app_key: app_key,
    search: search,
 }

// add this for state
if (state) params.state = state;


//this program formats the query paramaters
let searchQuery = formatQueryParams(params)


let searchURL = url + searchQuery;


fetch(searchURL)
.then(response =>response.json() )
.then(data => updateDOM(data))
.catch(err => {
    console.log(`${err.message}`)
  })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the required parameters in an object to the `fetchData` function like so

```
function fetchData(search, paramsObject)
```

Then inside your `params` object you can spread the `paramsObject` that you passed as a parameter earlier.

```
let params = {
    app_id: app_id,
    app_key: app_key,
    search: search,
    ...paramsObject
}
```